# How to enhance sweetness of a baked chocolate brownie?

Tags: baking, cake, brownies

I am not sure if it is even possible or not. I baked a almond and walnut chocolate brownie. While I was preparing the mixture I added extra cocoa powder, I though it will give the brownie a perfect chocolate color. This resulted in bit bitter brownie. The brownie is perfectly baked. I have never ever baked some thing so perfect and consistent like this brownie. Can I some how enhance  sweetness of this brownie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could thin a little syrup or honey with water and brush it on the top of the brownies so that it soaks in a sweetens them a little. Try it on one first.

Comment: OK, I will try it and let you know.But wont it destroy the brownie?

Comment: It should be ok providing you don't make it too liquid. You need to strike a balance between soakability and not being so wet it breaks the brownie up. That's why it's a good idea to test it on one brownie first.

Comment: I tried it on a part, used honey, tasted bit sweet. I guess I will buy a small tub of vanilla and will devour this brownie with ice cream and chocolate syrup. I have some how lost around 2 KGs and hopefully will regain my round shape soon :P. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

You could always frost the brownies, or you could also sprinkle powdered sugar with a sieve over the top to add a little extra sweetness.

Comment: My Wifey had this idea on first place but frost or sugar will not add the sweetness consistently.

Comment: @Kumar : maybed not if you left it in typical brownie-sized bits, but if you cut it into smaller bite-sized bits, and enrobe it in the frosting, or a sweet chocolate, you'd be able to get the balance you're looking for.

Comment: Katherine, wifey frosted half of the brownie, she didn't like it but I liked it :)

Answer (score 4):

Serve it with whipped cream or ice cream.

Next time, I imagine you'd have to increase the amount of sugar you use.

Answer (score 3):

I would crumble it all up on a mixing bowl then add some honey or goldrn syrup. I would the  mix it. Then I mould them back then freeze them.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, (as mentioned before), you could add a little bit more sugar, or you could add instant cocoa which is essentially cocoa powder with a bit of dried milk and sugar added. This would work, though the full flavour of the cocoa may disappear a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to slice the brownie down to very thin slices first, and then frost it as suggested by @Katherine Pitta. The combination of bitterness and sweetness will make it a very nice companion with tea or coffee.

Comment: all done and the brownie has been devoured, burp!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago, I ate a slice of brownie slightly warmed up with some vanilla ice cream and melted some milk chocolate on top. It was delicious, and perfectly balanced the bitterness of my brownie.

It would also work if you turned the brownies into cake pops!

Answer (score 0):

**Pour/spread over them sweeter chocolate melted and sprinkle lightly with high quality flaky salt like Maldon.** The chocolate is only for the purpose of the salt sticking to it. I mean literally 5-7 crystals per brownie square. This will work in ratio for brownie recipe 1:1:1:1:1 butter, chocolate,eggs,flour,sugar by weight. Next time I would use dark cocoa (nixtamalized), like the one which goes into Oreo. If you need to have more cocoa in it, the best I thing would be just very dark chocolate 70%+ at the start, without the cocoa. Chocolate has better balance in solids flavour.

Answer (score 0):

Solved a bland batch of almond-flour brownies by serving each square with,first, a good trickle of Hershey's no sugar chocolate syrup and then a good tablespoon of Breyer's "Carb Smart" vanilla ice cream. Diabetic heaven.

Answer (score -1):

If it were me, I would dump the idea that these were eat-alone brownies, and see what else could be done with them.  That bitter chocolate makes me think of Mexico.  How about this:  Oaxacan turtle sundaes, with vanilla ice cream, your brownies, caramel sauce, and ancho-dusted pecans (ancho is a dark red pepper with a fair amount of heat. Ground ancho can be found many places with a decent spice selection or Mexican grocery).  For extra points, sub cajeta (caramelized goats milk) for the caramel sauce

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try your own version of tiramisu. One piece at a time, pour very sweet coffee over it until it puddles on all sides of the brownie. Let it soak in for about 10-15 minutes. Mine tasted better, but still bitter. I’m slicing ACROSS the middle (sideways),sprinkling some sugar substitute IN it, replacing the top, and pouring coffee on again. Gonna try very soon!

Answer (score -2):

U could always crumble the brownies and add frosting, and make cake pops or “brownie pops” it’s super easy crumble the brownie mix in frosting the mold into a ball, poke a stick into it and dip into any coating (candy melts, icing, even frosting) add sprinkles on top for more sweetness, freeze and enjoy!